# LDAP authentication is not working while committing the authentication in LoginContext class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap, jaas

For the new client I have to replace application's JAAS authentication with LDAP.
Flow goes to login() of `javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext` class. Here it has two steps to authenticate

```
// module invoked in doPrivileged
        invokePriv(LOGIN_METHOD);
        invokePriv(COMMIT_METHOD);
```

`invokePriv(LOGIN_METHOD);` goes to JAAS login class or LDAP login class and come back as loginSucceeded = true.
But `invokePriv(COMMIT_METHOD);` fails for LDAP login. While debugging it in the API, it is returning false for status in this line

```
boolean status = ((Boolean)methods[mIndex].invoke
                (moduleStack[i].module, args)).booleanValue();
```

I am completely clueless about this issue. As it is API class I am not able to see variable values while debugging.
Could it be possible that creation of IntialContext during LDAP authentication is messing up with LoginContext of JAAS API.

```
Note: I know there is a JAASLDAP module available. I will be implementing that in next iteration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configured LoginModule is returning false from its commit() method. It should return true if its own login method succeeded.